# Game Center Leaderboard: new score doesn't show up instantly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store

I have the following code which reports score and also displays leaderboard. Everything seems to be okay but when I send it new updated score, it doesn't show the score on leaderboard unless I click on Challenges tab or All Time. Basically, it needs me to click on something else inside leaderboard so the leaderboard can refresh and display the most recent score.

```
func reportLeaderboardIdentifier(identifier: String, score: Int) {
    let scoreObject = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: identifier)
    scoreObject.value = Int64(score)
    GKScore.reportScores([scoreObject]) { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("Error in reporting leaderboard scores: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
func displayLeaderboard () {
    var gameCenterController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self
    self.vc.presentViewController(gameCenterController, animated: true , completion:nil)
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: GKScore.reportScores runs in a background thread. Are you displaying your leaderboard before the function returns to the main thread? Based on the code above, that seems to be the likely issue.

Comment: I am doing reportLeaderboardIdentifier(score: 10) inside the main code. When the user clicks on Leaderboard button, I call displayLeaderboard().

Comment: Also I am doing this in sandbox with test users and using simulator. Do you think its a bug in sandbox?

Comment: Calling `reportLeaderboardIdentifier(score: 10)` on the main thread doesn't make a difference. The code `GKScore.reportScores([scoreObject])` gets executed in a background thread, and therefore cannot be relied upon to "immediately" post a score to the leaderboard. The issue is almost positively that the score has not posted yet when you open the leaderboard.